# using geom_smooth in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a line with smoothed values.

my code is:

```
library(MASS)

ggplot(data=mcycle) +
  aes(x=times, y= accel) +
  geom_point(aes(x=times, y=accel),shape=1) +
  geom_smooth(loess) +
  theme_minimal()
```

what I am trying to do;

[image]

what I get instead;

[image]

Comment: Try `geom_smooth(span=0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(MASS)

ggplot(data=mcycle) +
  aes(x=times, y= accel) +
  geom_point(aes(x=times, y=accel),shape=1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 12), se = FALSE)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]